# Mudar tabela de autenticação, Laravel 5

Tags: autenticação, laravel-5, multiple

Estou a fazer uma plataforma que vai ter 3 sistemas de autenticação, um para os utilizadores comuns, outra para os admins, e ainda uma para obreiros.

Pensei que mudar o model e tabela em config->auth seria o suficiente mas pelos vistos não é.

ObreirosController:

```
class ObreiroController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        Config::set('auth.model', 'App\Obreiros');
        Config::set('auth.table', 'obreiros');
    }

    public function doLogin(Request $request) {

        $credentials = array(
            'username' => $request->input('username'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
        );

        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            Session::flash('flash_error', 'Something went wrong with your login chef');
            return redirect('/');
        }

        Session::set('auth', 'obra');
        return redirect('/obra/dashboard');
    }

    public function goDashboard() {
        return view('/obreiro/dashboard');
    }
}
```

UserController:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        Config::set('auth.model', 'App\User');
        Config::set('auth.table', 'users');
    }

    public function doLogin(Request $request) {

        $credentials = array(
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
        );

        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            Session::flash('flash_error', 'Something went wrong with your login chef');
            return redirect('/');
        }

        Session::set('auth', 'user');
        return redirect('/user/dashboard');
    }

    public function goDashboard() {
        return view('/user/dashboard');
    }
}
```

E o mesmo para o AdminController...

O Middleware:

```
class UserAuth
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $sessAuth = 'user';

        if (Auth::user() && Session::get('auth') == $sessAuth) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else if (Auth::user() && Session::get('auth') != $sessAuth) {
            Session::flash('flash_session_off', 'YOU SHALL NOT PASS' .$sessAuth);
            return redirect('/');
        }
        Session::flash('flash_session_off', 'you are off chef, please login again');
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Que é igual nos três, à excepção, de `$sessAuth`

Routes ex:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'userAuth'], function() {
    Route::get('/user/dashboard', 'UserController@goDashboard');
});
Route::post('/auth/user', 'UserController@doLogin');
```

Que também é igual nos três...

views/obreiro/dashboard:

```
Hello {{Auth::user()->username}}
```

Parece estar tudo bem mas quando tento na view imprimir o username, que é uma coluna que existe na tabela `obreiros` mas não existe na tabela `users`, `{{Auth::user()->username}}` ele não me imprime nada, parace ser uma string vazia, mas não é. Creio que não está a mudar a tabela de autenticação, que é sempre a dos `users`, mas não dá nenhum erro, como resolvo isso? Alguma forma melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: Mas a autenticação acontece de fato? Verificou se ele talvez esteja redirecionando para a view que vc mandou sem acontecer a autenticação? Ai por isso não tem oque mostrar quando vc manda imprimir.

Comment: Sim a autenticação acontece, mas o `Auth::user()` acaba por ser da tabela `users`, apesar de fazer o login com os detalhes (email, password) da tabela certa... O Auth::user() é que é sempre da tabela `users`... É muito estranho

Comment: rapaz... da uma olhada no laravel 5.2!

Comment: http://learninglaravel.net/what-are-laravel-52s-new-features

Comment: acho que o "php artisan make:auth" vai te ajudar rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o porquê de não dar. O problema é no middleware deveria estar também o dinamismo de mudança da tabela para autenticação, ou seja, no controller temos de mudar a `auth.table` que por default é `users`, isso já estava a ser feito mas temos também de mudar a tabela/model de `auth` nos middlewares correspondentes:

EX middlewares:

```
class ObraAuth
{

// acrescentar em cada middleware as tabelas/models correspondentes
public function __construct() {
    Config::set('auth.model', 'App\Obra');
    Config::set('auth.table', 'obreiros');
}

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $sessAuth = 'obreiro';

    if (Auth::user() && Session::get('auth') == $sessAuth) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else if (Auth::user() && Session::get('auth') != $sessAuth) {
        Session::flash('flash_session_off', 'YOU SHALL NOT PASS' .$sessAuth);
        return redirect('/');
    }
    Session::flash('flash_session_off', 'you are off chef, please login again');
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Eu não entendi bem, o que mudou? Poderia fornecer um resposta com detalhes? Isto pode ajudar outros usuários.

Comment: Esclareci melhor

Comment: A parece que melhorou mesmo, só não entendi aonde `ObraAuth` se encaixa e relação ao código da pergunta.

Comment: Eu tenho três sistems de autentição, obreiros, users, e admins. O meu problema é que a default table para autenticação nas rotas que exigiam ter alguém login ex: `/obreiros/dashboard` precisavam de ter ter a default table correspondente, se fosse admin seria a tabela `admins`, users seria `users` e obreiros seria `obreiros`. E consegui fazer isso definindo a tabela certa no construtor do middleware. Senão fizesse isso a tabela de auth que ficava nessas rotas restritas era sempre `users` que é a default em `config->auth`